# connecting external Oracle database to SAP system

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sap-basis

How to connect to external Oracle databases on a SAP system on Windows platform?

I have SAP installed on my machine and I want to connect an external Oracle database.

What I think is it is must to install an Oracle client to do this.
I have related SAR file. Also I have extracted in using `SAPCAR -xvf K*.sar` and got this.

[image]

But now I don't know what to do next?
Can anyone please elaborate the steps?

Comment: I'm sure the vendors provide documentation, no?

Comment: @OldProgrammer no, i do not have it..and stuck in this since 3 days...it would be great if you could help me out in this..thanks

Comment: or if any body could mail me any helpful document in this regard?
ankur7721@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You create a new connection in transaction DBCON. Test the connection using SA38 > ADBC_TEST_CONNECTION.

Read SAP Note 339092 for details.